# Can't build SciPy from source because pybind11 missing

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, raspberry-pi, pybind11

I have ssh'ed into my Raspberry Pi 3b+ on my Macbook. I am trying to install SciPy on Python 3.8, but apt-get does not work and installing through pip freezes my Raspberry Pi. I have even tried increasing swap size, but it still freezes. As a result, I am trying to build SciPy 1.6 from source, but when I run `sudo python3 setup.py build` and `sudo python3 setup.py install`, it returns `Error: 'pybind11' must be installed before running the build.`

I have installed pybind11 using `python3 -m pip install pybind` and `python3 -m pip install "pybind11[global]"`. I can even import pybind11 in the python shell. Here is my list of packages:

```
Package         Version
--------------- -------
cycler          0.10.0
Cython          0.29.21
future          0.18.2
kiwisolver      1.3.1
matplotlib      3.3.4
numpy           1.20.1
Pillow          8.1.0
pip             21.0.1
pybind11        2.6.2
pybind11-global 2.6.2
pyparsing       2.4.7
pyserial        3.5
python-dateutil 2.8.1
scikit-rf       0.16.0
setuptools      53.0.0
six             1.15.0
smbus2          0.4.1
```

Answer (score 3):

Use
"pip install pybind11"